Python ibm_db trying to resolve: Exception: Describe Param Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0150E Driver not capable
In trying to resolve the

"Exception: Describe Param Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0150E  Driver
not capable"

error that results from my statement:
"stmt, hp_id, user_id, first_string, first_code, second_string, second_code, reason = ibm_db.callproc(conn,
'SP_DEN_PRV_GET_PROVIDER_PRACTICE_NAME', (hp_id, user_id, first_string, first_code, second_string, second_code, reason))"

I try to apply a schema as I suspect that may be the issue. But I put a CURRENTSCHEMA= into my connection string.....also placed an entry for SchemaList into my db2cli.ini file and neither made a difference. So I have  tried a dozen variations inside the Python (3.12.2) script using copy and paste, to set the schema there from as many sites, and every one delivers a syntax error.  Does anyone have a Python SET SCHEMA statement format that works  ??
The db server is z/os. The create procedure is:
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DEN_PRV_GET_PROVIDER_PRACTICE_NAME (
-- ****************************************************************
-- * These are the input parameters specific to this procedure
-- ****************************************************************

IN P_IN_HP_ID                   CHAR(9),

-- ****************************************************************
-- * Manditory input, allows us to add caller to error message
-- ****************************************************************

IN P_IN_MNTD_USR_ID       CHAR(8),

-- ****************************************************************
-- * Manditory outputs, they are set in the error handler
-- ****************************************************************

OUT P_OUT_RET_CD          INTEGER,         -- SQLCODE
OUT P_OUT_RET_TEXT        VARCHAR(200),    -- DIAGNOSTIC INFO
OUT P_OUT_RET_RSCD        INTEGER,         -- REASON CODE
OUT P_OUT_RET_ERR_STMT    VARCHAR(200)     -- ERROR MESSAGE

The SQL columns for the above are:
P_IN_HP_ID         P      1 CHAR
P_IN_MNTD_USR_ID   P      2 CHAR
P_OUT_RET_CD       O      3 INTEGER
P_OUT_RET_TEXT     O      4 VARCHAR
P_OUT_RET_RSCD     O      5 INTEGER
P_OUT_RET_ERR_STMT O      6 VARCHAR                                                                            The Python values (rom my script) are:
hp_id = "000923196"
user_id = "LIDDVDP"
first_code = 0
first_string = " "
second_code = 0
second_string = " "

Please edit your question to supply missing facts that are essential to be able to answer the question:  the python type of every parameter, and the SQL-data-type of each of the parameters to the stored-procedure (i.e. show the signature , the create procedure line that shows the datatypes of each argument to the stored procedure.   ALSO please specify the Db2-server type (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows/cloud ) along with the version of the ibm_db module you are using.

The db server is z/os, the create procedure is:

Please add missing information db2level text output from client workstation, and the version of the ibm_db module (use pip show ibm_db) . Question is now Tagged with db2-zos  per your remark.

Name: ibm_db
Version: 3.2.3

If one uses a different format: stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, "CALL DB2TEST.SP_DEN_PRV_GET_PROVIDER_PRACTICE_NAME(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")                              the stmt create succeeds but any attempt to bind values for the ?s  afterward yields the same error as the origina;l stmt format does

This is consistent with the answer that the effective setting for DescribeParam is 0. A db2trc will show a definitive cause. Refer to docs.

A likely cause (but not the only one) of this symptom is that the config file(s) used by clidriver have a non-default setting specifically DescribeParam with a value of 0.
To prove this, either delete that setting from the config file(s) or ensure its value is set to 1 (which is the default).
The python ibm_db module, at currently shipping versions , unconditionally uses the clidriver service called SQLDescribeParam() when binding parameters, which means that if your config files (or your code via connection string or other methods) explicitly disables describing parameters then CLI0150E is guaranteed to be the result.
Other causes are possible (some examples below). You should always include the Db2-server platform in your question either via tags db2-zos, db2-luw, db2-400, or via plain text.
For your symptom you should also specify text output of the  db2level command where python runs.
Another possibility is that the target Db2-zos subsystem has its DESCSTAT parameter set to NO, which will not allow python ibm_db to operate, that parameter must be changed to YES, check with your Db2-for-zos DBA.
Another possibility is that the python script invokes the sproc incorrectly, i.e. some mismatch between formal-parameters and actual-parameters, or the sproc has a schema/collection-id that differs from the defaults, or there is a typo in the sproc name.
Your question shows the sproc signature with only 6 arguments as far as I can see, perhaps you accidentally truncated it while posting, but you invoke the sproc with 7 arguments. Check which schema contains the sproc and try using that qualifier in the ibm_db.callproc() instead of the unqualified sproc name.
Taking a db2trc -f ... , then python yourscript.py on the client side , and examining the formatted results (db2trc fmt -cli ... ) will usually show the true cause of the symptom. Refer to the Db2 Knowledge centre for details of the command lines for the db2trc tool on the client side.
See the documentation here.
